# Writing users list to the textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to be a data saved to list what i did

```
List<string> users = new List<string>();
```

and then on button click `users.Add(name);`.And i want to write the names to the txtBox here:

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    txtBoxUsers.Text += Environment.NewLine + user;
}
```

But when i "register" more users the output is like :

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

When i register user first time,it show the name just one time,right.But then,it multiply it what i dont want.I was trying to not use foreach,i used 3 more ways but no one was working. Code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string pass;
    private string name;
    private bool when = false;

    private List<string> users = new List<string>();

    public void regBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength < 4)
        {
            when = true;
            if (regTxtBoxPass.TextLength < 4)
            {
                     if (when == false)
                     {
                         progBar1.Value = 0;
                         MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                     }
                     }
                     regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.Red;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (when == false)
                     {
                         progBar1.Value = 0;
                         MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                     }
                     regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.White;
                 }
                 regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.Red;
                 progBar1.Value = 0;
                 MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (regTxtBoxPass.TextLength < 4)
            {
                    regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                regAge.Minimum = 0;
                regAge.Maximum = 150;
                if (regAge.Value >= 15)
                {
                    if(chkBox1.Checked){
                    regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.White;
                    regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.White;
                    regAge.BackColor = Color.White;
                    pass = regTxtBoxPass.Text;
                    name = regTxtBoxName.Text;
                    users.Add(name);
                    foreach (var user in users) {
                        txtBoxUsers.Text += Environment.NewLine + user;
                    }
                    regTxtBoxPass.Text = "";
                    regTxtBoxName.Text = "";
                    regAge.Value = 0;
                    progBar1.Value = 100;
                    MessageBox.Show("Your account has been succesfully created.", "Registration FINSIHED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                    else{MessageBox.Show("Please, accept condition terms.", "Accept it omg....",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    regAge.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    regAge.Value = 0;
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("You're too young for this :)", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void logBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logTxtBoxName.Text == name)
        {
            if (logTxtBoxPass.Text == pass)
            {
                progBar1.Value = 100;
                MessageBox.Show("You have beeon successfully logged in.", "Logged IN", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                progBar1.Value = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is wrong!", "Login failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        else {
            progBar1.Value = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is wrong!","Login failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are all 106 lines related to your question? Please remove everything what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to set the `Lines` property of your TextBox:

```
txtBoxUsers.Lines = users.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never clearing out your text box, simply adding all the users again when a new one is added.

This is likely what you're looking for:

```
users.Add(name);
txtBoxUsers.Text = string.Empty; // Clear the text first, txtBoxUsers.Clear() works too
foreach (var user in users) {
    txtBoxUsers.Text += user + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Otherwise, you could just add the new user instead of adding every user, then you wouldn't have to clear.

Answer (score 0):

I did it simply
 `    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string pass;
        string name;
        bool when = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List users = new List();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
    }


    public void regBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (regTxtBoxName.TextLength < 4)
        {
            when = true;
                 if (regTxtBoxPass.TextLength < 4)
                 {
                     {
                         if (when == false)
                         {
                             progBar1.Value = 0;
                             MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                         }
                         }
                     regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.Red;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (when == false)
                     {
                         progBar1.Value = 0;
                         MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                     }
                     regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.White;
                 }
                 regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.Red;
                 progBar1.Value = 0;
                 MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (regTxtBoxPass.TextLength < 4)
            {
                    regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("Choose password/name with minimal length 5", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                regAge.Minimum = 0;
                regAge.Maximum = 150;
                if (regAge.Value >= 15)
                {
                    if(chkBox1.Checked){
                    regTxtBoxName.BackColor = Color.White;
                    regTxtBoxPass.BackColor = Color.White;
                    regAge.BackColor = Color.White;
                    pass = regTxtBoxPass.Text;
                    name = regTxtBoxName.Text;
                    users.Add(name);
                    txtBoxUsers.Text += Environment.NewLine + name;
                    regTxtBoxPass.Text = "";
                    regTxtBoxName.Text = "";
                    regAge.Value = 0;
                    progBar1.Value = 100;
                    MessageBox.Show("Your account has been succesfully created.", "Registration FINSIHED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                    else{MessageBox.Show("Please, accept condition terms.", "Accept it omg....",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    regAge.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    regAge.Value = 0;
                    progBar1.Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("You're too young for this :)", "Registration ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void logBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logTxtBoxName.Text == name)
        {
            if (logTxtBoxPass.Text == pass)
            {
                progBar1.Value = 100;
                MessageBox.Show("You have beeon successfully logged in.", "Logged IN", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                progBar1.Value = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is wrong!", "Login failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        else {
            progBar1.Value = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is wrong!","Login failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

        }
```

`